# After using doctrine:schema:update --force

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm using Symfony 2.1 on Windows 7, additionaly I'm using XAMPP. I had some problems with using commands like

```
php app/console
```

but now I do it like this

```
c:/xampp/php/php.exe app/console
```

because It's my path to php. In that way it works however when I execute

`doctrine:schema:update --force`

doctrine, or PDO connects to the database using my network provider server, and it should use the server I have in parameters.yml file. But it uses user name from parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
database_driver:   pdo_mysql
database_host:     (server looks something like this: xx.yyy.kkk.pl)
database_port:     
database_name:     my_database_name
database_user:     my_database_user
database_password: my_pasword
```

The doctrine stuff from config.yml

```
  # Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

The server is external, becose my project already has been publicated on internet, and now I'm trying to change some things, on the internet. I don,t want to create mysql database on my machine.

I think that I'have wrong configuration, but I don't know what should I configure, and how.
Anyone knows what is wrong?

PS the error from console;

```
[PDOException]
```

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'database_user'@'aggp215.neoplus.adsl.tpnet.pl' (using password: TAK)

I'm using build-in console in Aptana, but I don't think it could matter

Comment: So it is picking up database_user but not database_host?  And you know this how?  Is there an error message you can post?

Comment: By the way, right click on Computer in your windows startup menu and select properties.  Then click on Advanced system settings and environment variables.  Add a variable called PATH with C:\xampp\php;C:\xampp\mysql\bin Exit out of your console window and make a new one.  app/console should now work without having to specify the php stuff.

Comment: Thanks for tip:) PATH now works, but error still exists, and it doesn't tell much:
[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'database_user'@'aggp215.neoplus.adsl.tpnet.pl' (using password: TAK)

the 'aggp215.neoplus.adsl.tpnet.pl' is adress of may livebox I belive. I can't works because this adress isn't adress of remote database

Comment: Post your doctrine stuff from config.yml.  I'm thinking you might be missing some percent signs i.e. user:     %database_user%

Comment: ok, I posted it. I don't see any mistakes, but something new occured: the website on local host now throw the same error as console, it worked properly however before I tried to use `doctrine:schema:update --force` command. So maybe I did something with cgi or php liblaries, but I don't remeber what at the moment. I'll check it and post if I get any results.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found changes that could cause a problem so I re-installed my xampp, hoping that connetion to database starts to work. But it still don't work. But when I changed the database_host in paramaters.yml on localhost pdo tried to connect to localhost. So I tried to connenct to another remote database, and pdo was trying to connect to some ip adress, that leads nowhere in browser. But it didn't try to connect on my network provider host. So maybe problem is caused by the remote database and server I chose to connect. For me the only solution is to change locacion of database, and I thing it would be localhost because that server works, and no errors occurs. Thanks for help, I hope my solution will help someone.